# Pandas: sum column until condition met in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sum the `value` column until I hit a `break`.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'break': [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]})`

```
   value  break
0      1      0
1      2      0
2      3      1
3      4      0
4      5      0
5      6      1
6      7      0
7      8      0
```

Expected output

```
   value  break
0      6      1
1      15     1
```

I was thinking a group by but I can't seem to get anywhere with it. I don't even need the `break` columns at the end.

Comment: Your code doesn't create the print out (missing row `6,7`)

Comment: That is correct, since there is no `1` in the `break` col after index 5 there is no sum, so index `6,7` shouldn't be in the answer

Comment: I mean `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` only creates a dataframe with 6 rows, unlike the printout. I'm not talking about the expected output.

Comment: oh sorry about that, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, try groupby on reverse cumsum:

```
(df.groupby(df['break'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1],
            as_index=False, sort=False)
   .sum()
   .query('`break` != 0')  # remove this for full data 
)
```

Output:

```
   value  break
0      6      1
1     15      1
```

Comment: Wow, how do you even think of that. One note: to make it more precise, I would replace `sum` with `['value'].sum()` in the event there are more columns

Comment: I left `break` in for `sum` intentionally so that `query` works. So if you have more columns, then the more precise version would be `[['value','break']].sum()`.

Comment: Congrats on your six-figure digits!